# How to pass variable to url when a link is click?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm new to php and I've encountered a problem on school project. The question I have is, as the question suggested, to pass variable to url when a link is click. My problem is I have a drop down menu, which displays a category of menu products, e.g. food, drinks, desert. And when I click on the food category, the url will display :

```
 http://localhost/products.php?menu=food
```

and if I click on the drinks category the url will display:

```
http://localhost/products.php?menu=drinks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select name="color" id="dropdown">
   <option value="food"> food </option>
<option value="drink"> drink</option>
</select>
```

Jquery for get the dropdown value

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
   var menu = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = 'your_url.php?menu='+menu;
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! Does it work for links using <a> tags as well?

Comment: can u pls elaborate more?

Comment: Hi sorry for not being elaborate
 <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" value="food">Food</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" value="drinks">Drinks</a></li>
What I'm intended on using is <a> tags so that when a user click on food category under menu, the url will display "?menu=food".

Comment: `$('.dropdown dropdown-menu a').click(function(){
    var menu = $(this).attr('value');
    window.location.href = 'your_url.php?menu='+menu;
});`